# How to enable NegotiateServiceCredential in WCF when using CustomBinding

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-security

I have a client that use CustomBinding to consume a web service. I'm setting the service and client certificate before sending my request, but this way I need to know the service certificate to use and have it installed in the client machine. I'd like to let the service to provide the current certificate so I don't have to update it every time it changes.

I know this can be done when using WSHttpBinding by setting NegotiateServiceCredential to True through the Security property, but since I'm using CustomBinding there is not such a property and I don't know where to set  NegotiateServiceCredential to True.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a CustomBinding that works over HTTP and has a [MessageSecurityOverHttpElement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.messagesecurityoverhttp(v=vs.110).aspx) element on it.  There you you'll find a [NegotiateServiceCredential](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.configuration.messagesecurityoverhttpelement.negotiateservicecredential(v=vs.110).aspx) property which will allow to enable/disable the feature.

This link should get you started writing a [Custom Binding with a SecurityBindingElement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730305(v=vs.110).aspx). From there work your way up until you manage to add the MessageSecurityOverHttpElement.

Comment: Thanks, Jorge. It seems to be that I should use "WSDualHttpBinding" since it's the only binding class that contains a security property to get access to NegotiateServiceCredential. But could not find any information about which binding element I should add to my customBinding to get it working. By the moment I guess I'll keep updating the service certificate on every client.
Thanks again.

Comment: Is there any reason why you need WSDualHttpBinding and can't just use WSHttpBinding? WSDualHttpBinding is quite complex beause it opens another channel for duplex callbacks and unless you can't find any other way around your problem, you should really stay away from WSDualHttpBinding :)

Comment: Since info about MessageSecurityOverHttp class says it is used with wsDualHttpBinding I didn't think nothing else. Anyway we opt for a differente approach and built a tool to install the remote server certificate in just one repository and every client consumes a web service and install that certificate when it is published. Thanks for your help.